# No main method found in project

Tags: algorithm, kotlin

Hello everyone I'm new in programming. I'm learning Kotlin, I'm trying to find *perimeter* and *area* of a square with Pair. But I've got follow problem

> No main method found in project.

this is my code

```
fun main(a: Int) {
   val coordinates= Pair("Square", a)
   
   val side = coordinates.second
    
    val perimet = side*4
    val area = side*2
    
   
   println("Периметр: ${perimet}; Area: ${area}")
}
```

**I'm learning also algorithms by myself it's  very difficult ((**

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you positive the area of a square is half its perimeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main method must either not have a parameter or have a parameter whose type is `Array<String>`.

Method 1. Delete the parameter `a` from the parameter of the `main` function, and somehow assign a value *in* the main function.

For example,

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val a = readLine()!!.toInt()

    val coordinates = Pair("Square", a)
    ...
}
```

Method 2. Change the type of the parameter of the main method, and provide it at the same time when the program is executed as a command line argument.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = args[0].toInt()

    val coordinates = Pair("Square", a)
    ...
}
```